# Input validation in Terraform ( validation based on another variable )

Tags: terraform

I'm creating VM using Vsphere provider. Where OS template is selected based on OS_Type (redhat, windowsserver) && OS_version (8.4, 8.5 for redhat or 2019, 2020 for windowsserver).

I'm using local variable for this condition;
locals.tf:

```
locals {
  vm_templates = {
     redhat = {
       8.4 = {
       template = "OS template"
       }
       8.5 = {
       template = "OS template"
       }
     }
    windowsserver = {
      2019 = {
      template = "OS template"
      }
      2020 = {
      template = "OS template"
      }
     }
     }
     vm_template = local.vm_templates[var.os][var.os_version]
    }
```

main.tf:

```
data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template" {
name = "${local.vm_template["template"]}"
```

Variable.tf

```
variable "os" {
   validation {
      condition  = contains(["redhat", "windowsserver"], var.os)
      error_message = "valid values are redhat or windowsserver"
 }
}

variable "os_version" {
   validation {
      condition  = contains(["8.4", "8.5", "2019", "2020"], var.os_version)
      error_message = "valid values are "8.4", "8.5", "2019", "2020"
 }
}
```

This one works perfectly, however version should be depends on OS_type, for instance if I choose OS_type : redhat and OS_version : 2019, it should prompt error.

Comment: Those two variables should likely be combined into one.

Comment: But my requirement is to get two different variable OS and OS version and select template based on the OS and OS version.

Comment: You can also do that with one variable.

Comment: You can't do this with TF. Your requirement is incorrect.